# I've rendered a shere to the Glut Window now how do I make it move around with the keyboard?

Tags: opengl, emacs, common-lisp, glut, game-physics

Cutting and pasting the cl-glut-examples code I rendered a sphere to the display.  Now how do I move It on a x,y and z axis using the keyboard. Also is there an online resource to learn game programming in CL-OpenGL or how to make stuff like walls and dirt and houses and characters so I can create a 3D world and move characters around in it and come up with game logic for it.

Here is my code so far:

```
(defclass glut-teapot-window (glut:window)
()
(:default-initargs :width 948 :height 990 :title "glut-teapot.lisp" 
                  :mode '(:single :rgb :depth)))

(defmethod glut:display-window :before ((window glut-teapot-window))
(gl:clear-color 0 0 0 0)
(gl:cull-face :back)
(gl:depth-func :less)
(gl:disable :dither)
(gl:shade-model :smooth)
(gl:light-model :light-model-local-viewer 1)
(gl:color-material :front :ambient-and-diffuse)
(gl:enable :light0 :lighting :cull-face :depth-test))

(defmethod glut:display ((window glut-teapot-window))
(gl:load-identity)
(gl:translate 0 0 -5)
(gl:rotate 100 1 1 0)
(gl:light :light0 :position '(6000 1000 15 0))
(gl:light :light0 :position '(2000 300 3000 0))
(gl:clear :color-buffer :depth-buffer)
(gl:color 1 1 1)
(gl:front-face :cw)
(glut:Solid-Sphere 1 10 10)
(gl:front-face :ccw)
(gl:flush))

(defmethod glut:reshape ((window glut-teapot-window) width height)
(gl:viewport 0 0 width height)
(gl:matrix-mode :projection)
(gl:load-identity)
(glu:perspective 50 (/ width height) 0.5 20)
(gl:matrix-mode :modelview)
(gl:load-identity))

(defmethod glut:keyboard ((window glut-teapot-window) key x y)
(declare (ignore x y))
(when (eql key #\Esc)
(glut:destroy-current-window)))

(defun glut-teapot ()
(glut:display-window (make-instance 'glut-teapot-window)))
(glut-teapot)
```

Answer (score 8):

As I don't know your experience with opengl I'm going to write this answer for me a year back (when I knew nothing of opengl and was trying to learn using common lisp).

The cl-opengl library is a fairly tight wrapper around opengl, by this I mean most opengl functions have a direct equivalent in cl-opengl. This is good as it means that you will be able to take online tutorials for opengl using c & c++ and, with only a bit of mental strain, convert them to lisp.

The downside of it being a very tight wrapper around opengl is that opengl is not very lispy, by which I mean the style of good opengl code is very unlike good lisp code. This is definitely something that can be improved once you have got the hang of cl-opengl though.

Next, opengl is a library with two very different paradigms contained within it. There is old style
opengl (which uses gl-begin and gl-end) and new style opengl which is based on shaders is probably what you want if you want to do fancy effects in the future! The pain is that most of the good tutorials online are for old style opengl or mix the two in a way I found super confusing. Therefore I personally suggest the following tutorial for learning modern opengl:
http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Once your through just the first 4 chapters you will understand enough opengl to be able to use the opengl wiki without too much pain. I say this as at first I found the opengl language wiki to be REALLY confusing as I had no context of how all the information should fit together.

Right now on to GLUT. GLUT is cool...But it gets very limiting very fast. I really suggest switching to SDL. Luckily some brilliant people have made SDL in lisp pretty nice to use in common-lisp and have called it lispbuilder-sdl.
http://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/wiki/LispbuilderSDL

OK so how should you get going?:

- Get quicklisp: I'm assuming you're using this already, but if not, GET IT NOW! It makes getting up-to-date packages for common lisp so much easier. http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/
- Next, get lispbuilder (ql:quickload :lispbuilder-sdl)
- Get familiar with opengl using the arcsynthesis tutorial. It really was the best way of getting the understanding I needed to be able to code modern opengl.
- Write the examples from the arcsynthesis tutorial in lisp.
- Make some functions and macros to make your opengl work nicer in lisp.

I'm only a few months ahead of you on this road and getting started was a real pain, but totally worth it. I'm sorry if you are skilled up on opengl and thus this answer was too basic for you! If so let me know and I will try to put a better answer up.

Below is the basic code to get up an opengl window and context in SDL, to handle events (your user input will go here) and to redraw the frame (nothing to draw yet but you will fill it with the stuff from the arc synthesis tutorial!).

Also I have added a helper function and macro. First is 'continuable' which will mean that if an error happens in the code inside it there will be an option in the error result to continue the program (Really handy so that you don’t have keep starting the demo again and again). Also there is update swank which will mean that even while the demo is running you can still use Slime (you are using [slime](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) right? If not GET IT!)

```
(defun init ()
  (print 'initialise-stuff-here))

(defun draw ()
  (gl:clear-color 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0)
  (gl:clear-depth 1.0)
  (gl:clear :color-buffer-bit :depth-buffer-bit)
  (gl:flush)
  (sdl:update-display))

(defun reshape (width height)
  (print width )
  (print height)
  (gl:viewport 0 0 width height))

(defmacro continuable (&body body)
  "Helper macro since we use continue restarts a lot
   <remember to hit C in slime or pick the restart so errors don't kill the app>"
  `(restart-case (progn ,@body)
     (continue () :report "Continue")))

(defun update-swank ()
  (let ((connection (or swank::*emacs-connection*
                        (swank::default-connection))))
    (when connection
      (swank::handle-requests connection t))))

(defun run-demo ()
  (sdl:with-init ()
    (sdl:window
     640 480 :opengl t
     :resizable t
     :opengl-attributes '((:sdl-gl-doublebuffer 1)
                          (:sdl-gl-alpha-size 0)
                          (:sdl-gl-depth-size 16)
                          (:sdl-gl-stencil-size 8)
                          (:sdl-gl-red-size 8)
                          (:sdl-gl-green-size 8)
                          (:sdl-gl-blue-size 8)))
    (init)
    (reshape 640 480)
    (setf cl-opengl-bindings:*gl-get-proc-address* #'sdl-cffi::sdl-gl-get-proc-address)
    (sdl:with-events ()
      (:quit-event () t)
      (:VIDEO-RESIZE-EVENT (:w width :h height)
                           (reshape width height))
      (:idle ()
             (continuable (update-swank))
             (continuable (draw))))))
```

Ok, that’s it, have fun!

Comment: Thank you  very much my good man ...that was a thorough and very informative answer....as I had just figured out how to move the sphere on my own...your answer gave me direction for my next endeavors.... hats off to you sir! = )